# Should a child ViewModel be able to change on Parent ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a situation and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correct.

I have  a `ApplicationViewModel` that is my "shell" for my whole application.

And within that viewmodel I have other child-ViewModels.

```
    public ApplicationModelView()
    {
        ModelViewPages.Add(new GameViewModel());
        ModelViewPages.Add(new EditGameViewModel());
        //Set Current HomePage
        CurrentPage = ModelViewPages[0];
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public BaseModelView CurrentPage
    {
        get { return _currentPage; }
        set { _currentPage = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public List<BaseModelView> ModelViewPages
    {
        get
        {
            if (_modelViewPages == null){_modelViewPages = new List<BaseModelView>();}
            return _modelViewPages;
        }                        
    }
    #endregion
```

In my `GameViewModel` I display a list of objects from my model `GamesModel` that contains title,description etc.

When I click on an item in this list it becomes selected and then I want to change my View to `EditGameViewModel` with a button but I'm not sure if how to do it.

**How can I get my child-ViewModel to change content in my parent-ViewModel?
Or should the child even do that?**

**EDIT**

[How I want it to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN2L1.png)

I want when I select an item and click on button that I change from the view `GameViewModel` to `EditGameViewModel` with the data that I have selected from the list.

```
 public void EditGame(object param)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("From EditGame Function"); HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE VIEWMODEL ON MY APPLICATIONVIEWMODEL
    }
    public bool CanEditGame(object param)
    {            
        return SelectedGame != null;
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You want that the panel/view showing the GamesModel list to be completely replaced by a panel/view of the selected EditGameViewModel? Or do you only want the view of the single selected item change to a an EditGameViewModel item view within the view of the GamesModel list (based on your very brief code example i would believe in this)? Your doodles are unfortunately not very helpful in explaining what you actually want to do...

Comment: @elgonzo added a picture to hopefully explain more what I want. But I want to replace GamesModel list with EditGameViewModel and display that View.

Comment: I see. Do you already know how to work with commands in WPF? (Commands will be crucial to "weakly" link this kind of interaction logic with your viewmodel(s))

Comment: @elgonzo Yeah I know it works (kinda). Still learning but I have the basics down. What do you mean with "weakly" ?

Comment: With "weakly" i meant avoiding strong, inflexible (code) dependencies between your XAML presentation and your viewmodel code.
Just a few pointers in how to proceed: You don't need the _modelViewPages collection. It is redundant and unnecessary.
In the XAML item template for each game object instance, create a button which you bind to a command. The CommandPrameter
of this button you bind to the game object instance (a-ka the item) itself. Where is the command coming from? It should be provided by the
ApplicationViewModel (through a static readonly property, for example). (contd...)

Comment: You can implement this command and its command handler in ApplicationViewModel itself.
This command handler will receive the command parameter as set by the button invoking the command -- which will be the game
object instance associated with the particular button, if you did set up the XAML correctly. All you need to do is to set the DataContext of your application window (or whatever is your main panel) to a EditGameViewModel object you create with the game object instance. So, basically your main application view switches from the GameViewModel view to a EditGameViewModel view. (contd..)

Comment: Finally, change the name of your current GameViewModel. It is a view model for a list of games, not a view model for a single game, right? Call it GameListViewModel, for example. At the end of all this, all you need to worry then is how to switch back to the game list (another command, another button ;) )

Comment: Oops, i forgot to mention one thing: Since you switch the view models in the DataContext of your main application panel, you will also have to provide two templates (one for each view model; one for your ApplicationViewModel, and the other for EditGameViewModel) in the resource dictionary of the main panel (or wherever you have your templates...)

Comment: @elgonzo Ah okey now I start to understand what I should do. Yeah it seems better to remove my "list" of ViewModels and just work with a single content that switch based on the ViewModel. But shouldn't I switch between GameViewModel and EditGameViewModel? Since ApplicationViewModel is my "Base"-ViewModell and contains the shell for the other ViewModels.

Comment: IMHO, the answer posted below is overkill and distracts from the main question, which is "should the child view model directly modify/interact with the parent view model?" To which, I'd say the answer is "no". But there are so many different ways to approach it, and this is primarily opinion based as well, that your question is ill-suited to Stack Overflow. I will say, I would implement it such that the child view model raises some event (property changed, or something specific to the behavior) that the parent view model reacts to, and thus can modify itself in response.

Comment: Ideally, you will avoid any dependency on the parent by the child at all. Typically, this is achieved through designs that fall into the broad description of "inversion of control", of which the C# `event` feature is an example.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yeah I understand that my question might be opinion-based in some sense but I needed a "start-point" to continue research this topic. And I was given it with the example down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer something that works, but could be questionable. It all really depends on how you plan for your application to function.

First, similar to your MainViewModel, you want something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject //ObservableObject being a property change notification parent
{
    //Current view will always be here
    public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //By default we will say this is out startup view
        Navigate<RedViewModel>(new RedViewModel(this));
    }

    public void Navigate<T>(BaseViewModel viewModel) where T : BaseViewModel
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel as T;
        Console.WriteLine(ViewModel.GetType());
        OnPropertyChanged("ViewModel");
    }
}
```

Now, since we are navigating this way, every child view needs to derive from `BaseViewModel`.

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private MainViewModel _mainVM;

    public BaseViewModel(MainViewModel mainVM)
    {
        _mainVM = mainVM;
    }

    protected void Navigate<T>() where T : BaseViewModel
    {
        //Create new instance of generic type(i.e. Type of view model passed)
        T newVM = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), _mainVM);
        //Change MainViewModels ViewModel to the new instance
        _mainVM.Navigate<T>(newVM);
    }
}
```

Now we just really need to see how we are going to have child views delegate this call of change. So we will have a BlueView.

```
public class BlueViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //Relay command to call 'ToRed' function
    public ICommand ChangeToRed
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(ToRed); }
    }

    //Requires MainViewModel for BaseViewModel
    public BlueViewModel(MainViewModel main) : base(main)
    {

    }

    //Calling BaseViewModel function. Passed BaseViewModel Type
    public void ToRed(object param)
    {
        Navigate<RedViewModel>();
    }
}
```

And a RedView:

```
public class RedViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    //Relay command to call 'ToBlue' function
    public ICommand ChangeToBlue
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(ToBlue); }
    }

    //Requires MainViewModel for BaseViewModel
    public RedViewModel(MainViewModel main) : base(main)
    {

    }

    //Calling BaseViewModel function. Passed BaseViewModel Type
    public void ToBlue(object param)
    {
        Navigate<BlueViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Our MainWindow.xaml could look like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

Doing this all children will be able to call to their parent that they would like a change. The BaseViewModel holds this parent for all children who derive, so they can pass it back and forth during navigation like a baton.

Again, Navigation all really depends on how you are using, building and planning for your application. It's not always a one size fits all way.

Comment: Dude thank you so much! I will check this out. Even if it doesn't "fit" my type of project it can probably still give me more information in how to deal with this :). Thanks again!